# imagettftext() not working

Tags: php

```
/*create watermark*/

    // Create the image
    $im = imagecreate(460, 50);

    // Create some colors
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 230, 231, 232);
    $dark_grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 130, 133);

    // The text to draw
    $text = "foobar";

    // Set the enviroment variable for GD
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

$font = 'Tondu_beta';



    // Add the text
    imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 15, 35, $dark_grey, $font, $text);


    $wm_w = imagesx($im); //get width
    $wm_h = imagesy($im); //get height

    $wmresource = $im; //watermark resource

//imagejpeg($wmresource);

/*end watermark*/
```

The font file is Tondu_Beta.ttf. The code above worked just fine in my local machine, but it only gave me grey box after uploading to live server. What's wrong here? Thanks ^^

**UPDATE**: I remember it gave me this error: `Could not find/open font bla.bla..bla...`

Comment: Check the error logs and see.

Comment: Maybe your live server doesn't have the font?...

Comment: Does the script know to look for the font in that folder?

Comment: Your failure to specify the full name of the font, with proper capitalization, is also quite self-explanatory. XP Also, a lot of examples I've seen show the font name with `.ttf` attached to the end (e.g.: `$font = 'arial.ttf'`, etc.). Maybe give that a try as well?

Comment: Does your web server have permissions to read the .ttf file? Check the CHMOD settings.

Comment: Depending on the version of GD you have installed, you could be running into an old bug: "When using versions of the GD library lower than 2.0.18, a space character, rather than a semicolon, was used as the 'path separator' for different font files. Unintentional use of this feature will result in the warning message: Warning: Could not find/open font. For these affected versions, the only solution is moving the font to a path which does not contain spaces."  The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) have more explanation (check the fontfile section)

Comment: I have, and it's the doc's examples that show the extension. Have you looked at those examples yet? Your disparaging attitude is really not motivating me to help you out here.

Comment: Then did you read the first part of that comment of mine about correct capitalization? Or were you too busy trying to find ways to laugh at someone who's wasting his own time trying to help you with your problems?

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
"./Tondu_beta.ttf"
```

worked for me when both font and php file were in root directory

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory. Your live server doesn't have the font in question (Tondu_Beta.ttf) installed. Install the font onto your server, or choose a font your server does have.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php):

> fontfile
>
> The path to the TrueType font you wish to use.
>
> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename along a library-defined font path.
>
> When using versions of the GD library lower than 2.0.18, a space character, rather than a semicolon, was used as the 'path separator' for different font files. Unintentional use of this feature will result in the warning message: Warning: Could not find/open font. For these affected versions, the only solution is moving the font to a path which does not contain spaces.
>
> In many cases where a font resides in the same directory as the script using it the following trick will alleviate any include problems.

```
<?php
// Set the enviroment variable for GD
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

// Name the font to be used (note the lack of the .ttf extension)
$font = 'SomeFont';
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't my code already have your code? My GD version is 2.0.34

Comment: Ah, I missed that . . . if that's the case, I'd agree with the others and the case difference in the font file name is the gotcha . . .