# imagefttext() and imagettftext() giving strange results

Tags: php

I have an issue with getting `imagefttext()` and `imagettftext()` working in php.

This is a similar question to [imagettftext() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617484/imagettftext-not-working)
however I am not given an error.  I will simplify my code here to show what the basis of it is.
I have tried each line below.

No errors:

```
imagefttext($image2, 20, 0, 0, 20, $white , 'Alien-Encounters-Regular', "testing");

imagefttext($image2, 20, 0, 0, 20, $white , 'Alien-Encounters-Regular.ttf', "testing");

imagefttext($image2, 20, 0, 0, 20, $white , './Alien-Encounters-Regular.ttf', "testing");

imagettftext($image2, 20, 0, 0, 20, $white , 'Alien-Encounters-Regular', "testing");
imagettftext($image2, 20, 0, 0, 20, $white , 'Alien-Encounters-Regular.ttf', "testing");
imagettftext($image2, 20, 0, 0, 20, $white , './Alien-Encounters-Regular.ttf', "testing");
```

All of the above produce a series of white boxes where there should be a letter.  To further troubleshoot I took each line above and uploaded it and tried it.  I then changed the "A" in the font file name to "a" and none of them worked telling me this is a Unix based server. (caps matter) Below I'll post a working bit of code that produces an image with text.

```
imagestring( $image2, 4, 10, 5, "testing" , $white );
```

I know that FreeType is installed to the server else it would not even give me an image at all throwing an error when I try to use it.  I have not tried another method of setting the font file as that is not needed in this case. (It reads the file anyway. Else it would give me an error.)

[image]

**UPDATE:** This is now resolved thanks to Elias, I had a small part of code out of about ~1500 lines of code that was a fragment of old code. This code was `imagealphablending($image2, false)` and `imagettftext()` as well as `imagefttext()` do not work with alphablending off (Set to false.)  I removed the code and it now works as expected. See below for how it looks now.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some issues which might be relevant:

- font file not found
- the font file cannot be processed
- the blending mode is set incorrect ([imagealphablending()](http://php.net/imagealphablending))

Comment: Font file was fount, (Else would throw an error which I would have recited.)  Font is being processed (else would throw the same error... I think.)  However your third point about the `imagealphablending` was absolutely spot on!   I will update my question to show how I resolved it.  I had accidently left `imagealphablending($image2, false)` in my code.

Comment: @ZizzyDizzyMC glad it worked! Consider accepting the answer or answering the solution and accepting it.

Comment: I've edited my question to show exactly what I was (unintentionally) doing wrong.  In the hopes someone else some day may have the same issue.